# Select a word from a table column when its not inside [square], (round) or {curly} braces

Tags: sql, sqlite

Using `Like` I can write the following SQL query to select a row only if the `input` column has `help` word.

```
select * 
from entry
where input like '% help %'
   or input like 'help %'
   or input like '% help'
```

How to change this SQL query to select rows if `help` is not inside `[]` or `()` or `{}`.

Sample Data:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|                            input                            |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| this is help { some help }                                  |
| help                                                        |
| another help [ help ]                                       |
| some text ( some words surrounding help. just for example ) |
| [ see help ] some text                                      |
| this is a sentence. { help }                                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Expected results:

```
+----------------------------+
|           result           |
+----------------------------+
| this is help { some help } |
| help                       |
| another help [ help ]      |
+----------------------------+
```

Comment: You need to post a good sample data and expected results in your question. so please edit your question and post the sample data and expected results as _formatted text_ not images.

Comment: This edit does not make the question clear, please edit your question and add a propper sample data and expected results as [_formatted text_](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)

Comment: @Sami thanks for guiding me kindly. Hope that the question is more clear now.

Comment: You must use "AND" and "OR" together. One of them for acceptable values and the other one for unacceptable values.

Comment: How about `Asking for {help}. help`?

Comment: @Sami it is valid. cause help is occurred outside brackets as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up to this:

```
select * 
from entry
where  
    trim(input) = 'help' or
    input like 'help %' or 
    input like '% help' or
    replace(replace(replace(replace(input, '[', '('), '{', '('), ']', ')'), '}', ')') like '% help %(%)%' or 
    replace(replace(replace(replace(input, '[', '('), '{', '('), ']', ')'), '}', ')') like '%(%)% help %' or
    (input like '% help %' AND instr(replace(replace(replace(replace(input, '[', '('), '{', '('), ']', ')'), '}', ')'), '(') = 0)
```

provided that there is only 1 pair of `()`, `[]` or `{}` in `input`.

Comment: Fails for `help` - [Check it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.16&fiddle=4e001486385803eff39eb4e3fc728791)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
WITH entry AS
(
  SELECT 'this is help { some help }' input
  UNION
  SELECT 'help'
  UNION
  SELECT 'another help [ help ]'
  UNION  
  SELECT 'some text ( some words surrounding help . just for example )'
  UNION
  SELECT '[ see help ] some text'
  UNION
  SELECT 'this is a sentence. { help }' 
)
SELECT input
FROM
(
    SELECT input,
           CASE WHEN InStr(input, '[') > 0 THEN
                     InStr(input, '[')
                ELSE
                (CASE WHEN InStr(input, '(') > 0 THEN
                           InStr(input, '(')
                      ELSE InStr(input, '{')
                 END)
           END Idx,
           InStr(input, 'help') IdxH
   FROM entry
)
WHERE (Idx = 0 OR Idx > IdxH);
```

Since, if the word `help` occure after `], ), }` then

```
WITH entry AS
(
  SELECT 'this is help { some help }' input
  UNION
  SELECT 'help'
  UNION
  SELECT 'another help [ help ]'
  UNION  
  SELECT 'some text ( some words surrounding help . just for example )'
  UNION
  SELECT '[ see help ] some text'
  UNION
  SELECT 'this is a sentence. { help }' 
  UNION
  SELECT 'Asking for [help]. help me'
)
SELECT input
FROM
(
    SELECT input,
           CASE WHEN InStr(input, '[') > 0 THEN
                     InStr(input, '[')
                ELSE
                (CASE WHEN InStr(input, '(') > 0 THEN
                           InStr(input, '(')
                      ELSE InStr(input, '{')
                 END)
           END Idx,
           CASE WHEN InStr(input, ']') > 0 THEN
                     InStr(input, ']')
                ELSE
                (CASE WHEN InStr(input, ')') > 0 THEN
                           InStr(input, ')')
                      ELSE InStr(input, '}')
                 END)
           END Ix,
           InStr(input, 'help') IdxH
   FROM entry
)
WHERE (Idx = 0 OR Idx > IdxH OR InStr(SubStr(input, Ix), 'help') > 0)
```

**Returns:**

```
+----------------------------+
|           input            |
+----------------------------+
| Asking for [help]. help me |
| another help [ help ]      |
| help                       |
| this is help { some help } |
+----------------------------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.16&fiddle=61a980edabd819aa95aa12434dcdd71c)**

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple solution:

```
SELECT * FROM entry
WHERE input LIKE 'help%'
OR input LIKE '%help'
OR input LIKE '%help%'
AND input NOT LIKE '%(%help%)%'
AND input NOT LIKE '%{%help%}%'
AND input NOT LIKE '%[%help%]%'
```

The result is like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.16&fiddle=7253b3e331ff620fc232fd96cae0f63d)